# serializers.ValidationError format output of an input dictionary

Tags: django

I just figured out the output was altered by serializers.ValidationError. I have error messages stored in dictionary to match field names:

```
   errmsg['password']='password is incorrect'
   errmsg['age']='age must be between 8 - 10'
   #raise the error
   raise serializers.ValidationError(errmsg)
```

and the output becomes:

```
   "password": ['password is incorrect'],
   "age":['age must be between 8 - 10']
```

But i want :

```
     "password": "Password is incorrect"
```

Any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing:

```
reply={}
for item in serializer.errors:

    reply[item]=serializer.[item][0]

return reply
```

till an easier and stable way is found.